# Fusion tables permissions: how to restrict so that android app can only add new entries?

Tags: android, permissions, google-fusion-tables

I'm writing an (Android) app (probably a website too) that logs some data from the user when they click a button. I'm currently playing with storing this data in a Google Fusion Table. How can I configure the permissions so that the app (or the website) is allowed to add an new entry to the table, and view it, but not change existing data?

I imagine I could do this by running a service in the middle that takes the data from the phone, and is auth'ed to write to the table, but would rather a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is not possible, as there is no "INSERT only" permission, if you are the editor of a table you actually can edit and insert data.

- see also [issue 538](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=538)

Maybe you can do something similar when using views, so a user can update this view, but not all the other data. Maybe you can hide the data from the editable view right after a user inserted it. Of course, this must be considered as a hack or workaround.

- to get the idea: [Flu Vaccine Finder example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/data_gathering)